# Is this possible to support iPhone X and iOS 8 in same project?

Tags: xcode, iphone-x

It seems that a `"Safe area layout guide before ios 9".` error will occur if I trigger the `Use Safe Area Layout Guides` in the least XCode, does it means supporting both devices is not possible? Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: In all of the testing I have done the answer is no. I struggled with until I decided to go check how many users still used iOS 8 for my app and it was none.

Answer (score 5):

It is totally possible to support iPhone X with a minimum target of iOS 8. (In fact, that's what we currently have in the Khan Academy app.)

What we do is apply the `safeAreaInsets` in our Swift code using the `#available` function, like so:

```
public override func safeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        super.safeAreaInsetsDidChange()
        self.contentCatalogHeaderView?.safeAreaInsetsTopOverride = safeAreaInsets.top
        self.collectionViewLayout.safeAreaInsetsTop = safeAreaInsets.top
    }
}
```

From your question, it sounds like you're debating whether to use the checkbox in a Storyboard to enable safe area insets. I'm not sure whether it's possible for a Storyboard to support iOS 8 if safe area insets are enabled (I suspect it's not possible). However, you can always store a reference to a layout constraint, and update its constant in your code using the above `#available` function.

(In Objective-C, the code looks nearly identical, just format it like this:

```
- (void)viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange {
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        [super viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange];
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    }
}
```